# Fibonacci aplicado al sistema de Score

Tags: c#

Buenas!

Me encuentro en una situación donde debo aplica la suceción de Fibonacci en un sistema de puntuación.

El ejercicio suena simple, pero no estoy encontrando la mejor forma de hacerlo, entonces decidí bucar opiniones.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo algo realizado hasta el momento. Pero con uno de los problemas que me encuentro, es poder sacar la cuenta de las X naves destruidas.

Acá dejo lo que he hecho hasta el momento.

```
 public  int fib(int n)
{
       if (n < 2)
       {
           return n;
        }
       else
        {
            return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
        }
        setScoreToPlayer.Score(n);
    }
```

Comment: en que se diferencia X de n?

Comment: Con X me refiero a cantidad de naves destruidas. Me confundí y puse X, pero sería N

Comment: Entonces cual es la diferencia entre n y N? Al parecer el número que buscas es el que le pasa por parámetro a `fib()`

Answer (score 2):

Podrias aplicar la formula de Fibonacci de forma simple y el valor lo multiplicas por 10

[Formula fibonacci](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fibonacci)

[The Fibonacci Numbers](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d0e913/the-fibonacci-numbers/)

Hay varios tipos de implementaciones, algunas usan recursividad

Sería algo como

```
int nave = 2;
int puntos = nave + (Fibonacci(nave) * 10);
```